# Where do I find the specifications of the FLSUN 42BYGH stepper motor?

Tags: stepper, replacement-parts, flsun

I would like to replace a NEMA 17 stepper motor for my FLSun SR (it clicks and the rotor eventually slides forward, causing it to offset layers). How do I find the specs for this motor?  They aren't listed on FLSun's website and I tried their contact us form.  The back of the motor has this written on it:

FLSUN STEP MOTOR
42BYGH718-B-28Q
LOT NO.210711

The total length of the motor is 47 mm.

Comment: [Hybrid Stepper Motor 42BYGH Series](https://www.promoco-motors.com/products/StepperMotors/42BYGH%20Series.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by Mick. The full datasheet can be found on [promoco-motors.com](https://www.promoco-motors.com/products/StepperMotors/42BYGH%20Series.pdf). Below is a table with electrical specifications from the mentioned datasheet.

[image: electrical specifications of 42BYGH stepper motor]